# How to declare variables inside Excel Function?

Tags: excel, vba

**Updated Post**

I have changed the code like.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function Isokinectic(streamVelocity As Double, sampleVelocity As Double, probeDiameter As Double, density As Double, particleDiameter As Double, viscosity As Double)

        Dim s As Double
        Dim stk_coefficent As Double
        Dim stk As Double
        Dim d As Double

        s = ((0.16 * 10 ^ -4) / particleDiameter) + 1
        stk_coefficent = (1 / (18 * viscosity)) * density * particleDiameter * particleDiameter * s
        stk = (streamVelocity / probeDiameter) * stk_coefficent
        d = 1 + (2 + 0.62 * (sampleVelocity / streamVelocity)) * stk
        Isokinectic = 1 + ((streamVelocity / sampleVelocity) - 1) * (1 - 1 / (d))

End Function
```

But it does not work. However, when add the sub MAIN (), like this. It works.

```
Option Explicit
Function Isokinectic(streamVelocity As Double, sampleVelocity As Double, probeDiameter As Double, density As Double, particleDiameter As Double, viscosity As Double)

        Dim s As Double
        Dim stk_coefficent As Double
        Dim stk As Double
        Dim d As Double

        s = ((0.16 * 10 ^ -4) / particleDiameter) + 1
        stk_coefficent = (1 / (18 * viscosity)) * density * particleDiameter * particleDiameter * s
        stk = (streamVelocity / probeDiameter) * stk_coefficent
        d = 1 + (2 + 0.62 * (sampleVelocity / streamVelocity)) * stk
        Isokinectic = 1 + ((streamVelocity / sampleVelocity) - 1) * (1 - 1 / (d))

End Function

Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox Isokinectic(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
End Sub
```

**Original Post:**

I tried to code an equation in excel function. But I got #value

```
Function Isokinectic(streamVelocity As Double, sampleVelocity As Double, probeDiameter As Double, density As Double, particleDiamter As Double, visocity As Double)

        Dim s As Double
        Dim stk_coefficent As Double
        Dim stk As Double
        Dim d As Double

        s = (0.16 * 10^ - 4 / particleDiameter) + 1

        stk_coefficent = (1 / (18 * viscosity)) * density * particleDiamter * particleDiameter * s

        stk = (streamVelocity / probeDiameter) * stk_coefficent

        d = 1 + (2 + 0.62 * (sampleVelocity / streamVelocity)) * stk

        Isokinectic = 1 + ((streamVelocity / sampleVelocity) - 1) * (1 - 1 / (1 + d))

        End Function
```

Anything I did wrong in this code?

Comment: It's running fine for me. How are you calling it?>

Comment: insert Function. Then type the variables.

Comment: Typo in the header  ***particleDiamter*** is not ***particleDiameter***  there may be other problems

Comment: Also ***visocity***

Comment: `Option Explicit` - make that the first line of every code module you have - you will avoid so many errors you will wonder how you lived without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little cleanup:

```
Option Explicit
Function Isokinectic(streamVelocity As Double, sampleVelocity As Double, probeDiameter As Double, density As Double, particleDiameter As Double, viscosity As Double)

        Dim s As Double
        Dim stk_coefficent As Double
        Dim stk As Double
        Dim d As Double

        s = ((0.16 * 10 ^ -4) / particleDiameter) + 1
        stk_coefficent = (1 / (18 * viscosity)) * density * particleDiameter * particleDiameter * s
        stk = (streamVelocity / probeDiameter) * stk_coefficent
        d = 1 + (2 + 0.62 * (sampleVelocity / streamVelocity)) * stk
        Isokinectic = 1 + ((streamVelocity / sampleVelocity) - 1) * (1 - 1 / (1 + d))

End Function

Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox Isokinectic(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! It works!

But when I remove the sub MAIN() part. And type =Isokinectic(), it won't work. Why is that?

Comment: it is #value. LOL

Comment: It works now. It seems that I need to insert the module in the VBA project. Not the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In your original post your have calculated s, d, stk but in no where in later stage you are getting the value for Velocity & other, is reason for the Value error. 
Since with a subroutine as you have put Value in formula it's working,, please write that command line in Function your Function will work, don't forget to pass value for Velocity from Cells.